# how to know rss feed link of my joomla website?

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I want to create iPhone application that can load all new post from my website in to my app.

my website was designed using joomla 3.3.6 so How can I get rss feed ling of website?

thank before hand

Answer (score 6):

Syndication Module creates a Syndicated Feed for the page where the Module is displayed. The page has to be a blog layout for the module to show/work. When the module is displayed, click on the RSS icon for a new page to get feed URL.

In addition,RSS feed only available for the following **Menu Item Type**:

1. Category Blog
2. Category List
3. Featured Articles

Once you have determined your Menu Item Type, you may just use the following URLs,for example:

```
http://your_joomla_url/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&id=14&Itemid=473&format=feed&type=rss (for RSS)
http://your_joomla_url/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&id=14&Itemid=473&format=feed&type=atom (for ATOM)
```

Answer (score 2):

Global **rss feed** options could be found under:

```
Content -> Article Manager -> Options -> Integration -> Show feed link
```

If you want to set up a feed from **specific categories**, you could create a menu item that include articles from these categories and enable feed link under:

```
Menus -> *Menu Name -> *Menu Item -> Integration -> Show Feed Link
```